# Copying with sudo permissions under ansible

Tags: ansible

I am having the following playbook in Ansible:

```
---
- hosts: ESNodes
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Copy Elasticsearch
    copy: src=~/elasticsearch-1.0.0.tar.gz dest=/opt/elasticsearch-1.0.0.tar.gz
  - name: Untar Elasticsearch
    action: shell cd /opt/ && tar xvfz elasticsearch-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

When running the playbook as follows:

```
bash-4.1$ ansible-playbook es_playbook.yml  -K 
sudo password: 

PLAY [ESNodes] **************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [isk-vsrv643]

TASK: [Copy Elasticsearch] **************************************************** 
failed: [isk-vsrv643] => {"failed": true}
msg: Could not replace file: /usr2/ihazan/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1393762341.08-257257560838959/source to /opt/elasticsearch-1.0.0.tar.gz: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr2/ihazan/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1393762341.08-257257560838959/source'

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/usr2/ihazan/es_playbook.retry

isk-vsrv643                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

It fails with a problem of permissions.

On the remote host I am unable to do:

```
-bash-4.1$ cp elasticsearch-1.0.0.tar.gz /opt/
cp: cannot create regular file `/opt/elasticsearch-1.0.0.tar.gz': Permission denied
```

But I can do:

```
-bash-4.1$ sudo cp elasticsearch-1.0.0.tar.gz /opt/
```

What am I getting wrong in the playbook?

Thx in advance

Comment: Could you run the playbook with -vvv ?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible is probably not even logging in. You are missing the `user` directive:

```
---
- hosts: ESNodes
  user: whatever_user_that_you_use_to_login_and_has_sudo_access
  sudo: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Copy Elasticsearch
    copy: src=~/elasticsearch-1.0.0.tar.gz dest=/opt/elasticsearch-1.0.0.tar.gz
  - name: Untar Elasticsearch
    action: shell cd /opt/ && tar xvfz elasticsearch-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

hazan, may be you are missing the user to make sudo in the destinations host: If you don't declare it in playbooks, you need to add extra vars in ansible-playbook command, for example:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --extra-vars "user=your_user"
```

Then, ansible will use "your_user" in the destination host to run tasks.